# Reading files and averaging the contents in Python

Tags: python

I am reading three different files and printing the output. However, I also want to print the average of each line from the three files. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
N = [1, 2, 3]
for i in N:
    filepath = r"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\Trials\{}\len_J.py".format(i)
    try:
        with open(filepath, "r") as f:
            content = f.read()
            print(content)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found:", filepath)
```

The current output is

```
1
2
3

4
5
6

7
8
9
```

The expected output is

```
4 #(1+4+7)/3
5 #(2+5+8)/3
6 #(3+6+9)/3
```

Comment: Why would you expect that output from your code? All you're doing is dumping the file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 files. Each file has a number of lines. Each line contains a single integer value

Therefore (using different file paths):

```
NFILES = 3

values = [[] for _ in range(NFILES)]

for i in range(NFILES):
    with open(f'/Volumes/G-Drive/File{i+1}.txt') as data:
        values[i] += map(int, filter(lambda x: x.strip().isdecimal(), data))

for t in zip(*values):
    print(sum(t)//len(t))
```

**Output:**

```
4
5
6
```

**Note:**

If any lines in any of the files contains something that cannot be converted to int then such lines will be ignored

Comment: I have the files ```1,2,3```. How can this be replaced ```for i in range(3):```?

Comment: Just add 1 to the value of i when constructing your file path just as I do in this example

Comment: Is it possible to add a condition that if one of the folders doesn't have this file, it will take average only of the folders which have this file? For example, right now three folders have the file, so the average is over three. Now if two folders have the file, it should be averaged over two.

Comment: @KeplerNick123 Yes it is possible to do that

Comment: It works but if one of the folders doesn't have the file, it runs into error.

Comment: @KeplerNick123 That is correct. Your question states clearly that there will be three files. You will need to ask a new question or edit this question to clarify your use-case. You will also need to state what should happen if any of the files contain an unexpected number of lines

Answer (score 2):

`read()` returns either a string or bytes. You're currently getting a string. You need to parse the integers on each line, save them in a list or numpy array and then you can call `np.average` to get the value you need.

Comment: Okay I will try...

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code for that:

```py
contents = "1\n2\n3"
num_array = contents.split("\n")

total = 0
for number in num_array:
    total += int(number)

print(total / len(num_array))
```

`contents` is the content you read from your files. You'll have to watch out if not every line in the file is a number because then the integer conversion will throw an exception.

Also I assume that the numers in the file are separated by newlines, if now you'll have to replace the character in the split statement.

Comment: This doesn't yield the expected output.

Comment: If you implement it right it should. Also what output are you getting. I need more information to help you here

Comment: This is the output I am getting: ```1
2
3
2.0

4
5
6
2.0

7
8
9
2.0```

Comment: Well I think you did not replace the contents variable with the actual contents of the files...

Comment: Now I did. But still getting an error: ```in <module>
    total += int(number)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''```.

Comment: That means that your files are not formatted like you mentioned in your question. Please edit it to include them